How can I install python dependencies for Nifi Python processors without the --no-cache-dir option to not download the packages everytime again
I am writing a Python processor for Nifi and while everything works, the developement process is really slow because even though hot reloading works, Nifi downloads the dependencies every time again.
This makes me have to wait before running the processor again.
I checked the logs and found that Nifi installs the dependencies with the --no-cache-dir option
2024-08-26 13:15:32,240 INFO [python-log-940] python.ExtensionManager Importing dependencies ['pandas', 'xlsxwriter'] for csvProcessor to /opt/nifi/nifi-current/./work/python/extensions/csvProcessor/0.0.1 using command ['/opt/nifi/nifi-current/./work/python/extensions/csvProcessor/0.0.1/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--no-cache-dir', '--target', '/opt/nifi/nifi-current/./work/python/extensions/csvProcessor/0.0.1', 'pandas', 'xlsxwriter']

There are some reasons I can think about why I do not want to cache the dependencies but for development it is really slow.
How can i disable this option?
I am Nifi in a docker container and attaching vscode to it and I am editing the file there. It seems a little complicated for developing these processors because for testing I have to rerun the processor from the web interface.
I would appreciate suggestions for improving the development experience.

Have you mounted a volume for /opt/nifi/nifi-current/./work/python/extensions?

No, why would I do that?

Because it would cache those files on your host rather than be lost when Nifi container / your machine restarts. More specifically, there is no uniqueness in that path, so there is no reason for it to re-download each time

That makes sense but I am more concerned about downloading the dependencies every time I edit the Python processor file while the container keeps running...

Does it actually download each time, though? Pip knows when the packages already exist on disk
